# Getting object as array in javascript with array.map() function

Tags: javascript, node.js

When using the array.map function I am getting some data in an object. However, I need to get it in an array. The problem occurs with the function for images.

EBIT:

Part of my code involving the array.map function looks like the following (sorry if the code seems confusing given the problem at hand, but there seemed to be some confusion since I had left out the rest of the code before):

```js
function getVenues(page, size, venues) {
  page = page || 0;
  size = size || 200;
  venues = venues || [];
  return axios
    .get(`https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/venues.json?apikey=MYAPIKEY&page=${page}&size=${size}&countryCode=DK`)
    .then(response => response.data._embedded.venues)
    .then(rawVenues => {
      rawVenues.forEach(venue => venues.push(venue));
      if (rawVenues.length < size) {
        // All done return the compiled list.
        return venues;
      }
      // Recurse over the next set of venues by adding another promise to the chain.
      return getVenues(page + 1, size, venues);
    });
}

function getEvents(page, size, events) {
  page = page || 0;
  size = size || 200;
  events = events || [];
  return axios
    .get(`https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events.json?apikey=MYAPIKEY&countryCode=DK&size=${size}&page=${page}`)
    .then(response => response.data._embedded.events)
    .then(rawEvents => {
      rawEvents.forEach(event => events.push(event));
      if (rawEvents.length < size) {
        // All done return the compiled list.
        return events;
      }
      // Recurse over the next set of events by adding another promise to the chain.
      return getEvents(page + 1, size, events);
    });

}

app.get('/tm2', (req, res) => {
  getVenues().then(rawVenues => {

    const venuesToBeInserted = rawVenues.map(venue => {
      return {
        sourceID: venue.id,
        venue: venue.name,
        postalCode: venue.postalCode,
        city: venue.city.name,
        country: venue.country.name,
        countryCode: venue.country.countryCode,
        address: !!venue.address ? venue.address.line1 : null,
        longitude: !!venue.location ? venue.location.longitude : null,
        latitude: !!venue.location ? venue.location.latitude : null,
        source: 'ticketmaster'
      };
    });

    // Return promise so errors bubble up the chain...
    return Venue.create(venuesToBeInserted).then(venues => {
      console.log("venues inserted");



      // Return promise so errors bubble up the chain...
      return getEvents().then(rawEvents => {

        const eventsToBeInserted = rawEvents.map(event => {
          return {
            name: event.name.trim(),
            slug: slugify(event.name.trim()).toLowerCase(),
            sourceID: !!event._embedded.venues ? event._embedded.venues.map(sourceIDs => {
              return {
                sourceID: !!sourceIDs ? sourceIDs.id : []
              }
            }) : [],
            tags: !!event.classifications ? event.classifications.map(tag => {
              return {
                tags: !!tag ? [tag.segment.name, tag.genre.name] : [],
              }
            }) : [],
            images: !!event.images ? event.images.map(image => {
              return {
                images: !!image ? image.url : []
              }
            }) : []

          }
        })

        // Return promise so errors bubble up the chain...
        return Event.create(eventsToBeInserted).then(events => {
          console.log("events inserted");

        });
      });
    });
  }).then(() => { // This then is fired after all of the promises above have resolved...
    return Event.find({}).select({
      genres: 1,
      tag: 1
    }).limit(30).populate('event').populate('venue').then(events => {
      console.log(util.inspect(events));
      res.send(events);
    });
  }).catch(err => { // Catches any error during execution.
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send(err);
  });
});
```

my current output looks like this:

```
images: 
   [ { images: 'url_1' },
     { images: 'url_2' },
     { images: 'url_3' } ]
```

I want to get it in the following format:

```
images: 
   [ { 'url_1' },
     { 'url_2' },
     { 'url_3' } ]
```

Comment: Consider posting a working example using the snippet tool (Ctrl+M), so that responders can post a precise solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm having a difficult time understanding why you inlined all of your `map()`'s. Would be much more readable if you broke up your code into smaller chunks and did validation, e.g. things like `!!event.classifications ? ... : []` somewhere else entirely, so that your code can be more concise.

Comment: Please don't post logs or other text as images.

Comment: That second format is invalid, your edited request doesn't even make sense.

Comment: It seems "Getting object as array" is not what you want. Please change your question's title + description. What you want is simply mapping an array.

Comment: Yeah, you are right ideaboxer. I get the array by using: images: event.images.map(image => image.url)

Answer (score 0):

I will avoid commenting further on how to better organize your code. For now, to obtain the desired result, just remove the object literal you've wrapped each of your calls to `map()` with. For example fixing the `images`, change from this:

```
images: !!event.images ? event.images.map(image => {
  return {
    images: !!image ? image.url : []
  }
}) : []
```

to this:

```
images: !!event.images ? event.images.map(image => {
  return !!image ? image.url : ''
}).filter(Boolean) : []
```

I'm not sure why your input `event.images` array would contain malformed objects without a `url` property, or be missing itself, but the `.filter(Boolean)` deals with those by removing any empty strings, specified in the third expression of the ternary operator `... ? ... : ''`.